# POST http://localhost:3000/api/mail 500 (Internal Server Error) while trying to send the message throught SendGrid Api key

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, sendgrid

This is my api/mail.js file:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const sgMail = require("@sendgrid/mail");

const { SG_API_KEY, FROM_EMAIL, TO_EMAIL } = process.env;

sgMail.setApiKey(SG_API_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { name, phone} = req.body;
  const msg = {
    to: TO_EMAIL, // Change to your recipient
    from: FROM_EMAIL, // Change to your verified sender
    subject: "Contact",
    html: `<p><strong>Name: </strong>${name}</p>
    <p><strong>Phone Number: </strong>${phone}</p>    
    `,
  };
  
  await sgMail.send(msg);
  console.log("email sent");
  res.status(200).json({ success: true });
}
```

This is my .env.local. with Api key that is fine and correct, with 'from email' and 'to email' file:

```
SG_API_KEY = XXX
```

This is my main Contact.js component file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'



function Contact() {
  
  const [mail, setMail] = useState({
    name: '',
    phone:'',
  })

  const {name, phone} = mail

  const handleChange = e => setMail({...mail, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/mail", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(mail),
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className='xl:mt-20 lg:mt-20 md:mt-20 mt-14 flex flex-col items-center'>
        <em id='Metropolis' className='uppercase mb-7 xl:text-[109.07px] lg:text-[109.07px] md:text-[89.07px] text-[39px]'>
        Let's be in touch.
        </em>

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="POST" className='xl:space-x-4 lg:space-x-4 xl:space-y-0 lg:space-y-0 space-y-5 mb-20 flex xl:flex-row lg:flex-row flex-col items-center'>
          
            <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} name='name' placeholder='YOUR FULL NAME' className='flex-grow border-2 border-black p-4 pl-4 font-Catamaran text-sm text-gray-500 w-[315px]'></input>
            <input type="text" value={phone} onChange={handleChange} name='phone' placeholder='PHONE NUMBER' className='flex-grow border-2 border-black p-4 pl-4 font-Catamaran text-sm text-gray-500 w-[315px]'></input>
            <button className='bg-[#2E2E2E] border-2 border-black text-white p-[14px] xl:w-[210px] lg:w-[210px] w-[315px] hover:bg-white hover:text-black transition duration-300 ease-in-out'>Send Request</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  )


}

export default Contact
```

This is the full error that is popping up in my VS code terminal:

```
error - ResponseError: Unauthorized
    at C:\Users\ASUS\OneDrive\Desktop\saida-website\node_modules\@sendgrid\client\src\classes\client.js:146:29
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  code: 401,
  response: {
    headers: {
      server: 'nginx',
      date: 'Mon, 20 Feb 2023 13:30:27 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '76',
      connection: 'close',
      'access-control-allow-origin': 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io',
      'access-control-allow-methods': 'POST',
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl',
      'access-control-max-age': '600',
      'x-no-cors-reason': 'https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=600; includeSubDomains'
    },
    body: { errors: [Array] }
  },
  page: '/api/mail'
}
```

[This is the proof that i already verified both of my email domains. P.S. I also verified and tried before with gmail.com email domain, but still nothing works :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8h3O.png)

Furthermore, after setting up my Api key i restarted my server several times, still nothing works. Also, i'm using my sender email that i mentioned in my SendGrid profile.

Comment: Hi, have you found out what was causing this error? I have the exact same issue, and can't figure it out.

Comment: I randomly started getting this error as well, despite having a working project for several months.
I'm getting a 500 error locally, and in production the email sends but the values from my form are undefined.

Again, it worked for several months, and I haven't changed anything about my API setup or fetch POST request.